# Assigning an id to table cells?

Tags: javascript

I want to add an id to the cells, so like row 0/col 0 would have an id of 1, row 0/col 1  would have an id of 2, and etc.

heres my code that im working with:

```
function init() {

var board = document.getElementById("board");
var NUM_ROWS = 6;
var NUM_COLS = 6;
for (row = 0; row < NUM_ROWS; row++) {
  var tr = document.createElement("tr");
     for (col = 0; col < NUM_COLS; col++) {
        var td = document.createElement("td");
        var img = document.createElement("img");
        img.src = 'images/image0.png';
        img.id = 'r' + row + 'c' + col;
        td.appendChild(img);
        td.addEventListener("click", function() {
           var img = this.childNodes[0];
           img.src = 'images/image1.png';
 });
    tr.appendChild(td);
}
board.appendChild(tr);

}
```

Comment: Please indent the code properly or provide a fiddle, otherwise it's pretty much unreadable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create and increment an `id` variable to assign each table cell an ordered numeric identifier:

```js
var board = document.getElementById("board");
var NUM_ROWS = 6;
var NUM_COLS = 6;
var id = 1;
for (row = 0; row < NUM_ROWS; row++) {
  var tr = document.createElement("tr");
  for (col = 0; col < NUM_COLS; col++) {
    var td = document.createElement("td");
    td.id = id++;
    var img = document.createElement("img");
    img.src = 'images/image0.png';
    img.id = 'r' + row + 'c' + col;
    td.appendChild(img);
    td.addEventListener("click", function() {
      var img = this.childNodes[0];
      // showPicture(img);
      console.log(img.id);
    });
    tr.appendChild(td);
  }
  board.appendChild(tr);

}
```

```html
<table id="board"></table>
```